# Survey probability. 6. A survey of 140 students was classified into the following table:

Tags: statistics

[image]

Randomly select a student and let A = {Male}, B = {Freshman}, and C = {Jr. or Sr.}.

I want to make sure I got these right.

1. Find P(A $\bigcup$ B). I got 0.65.
2. Find P(A|C). I got 1.65
3. Are the events B and C mutually exclusive? Explain your answer.

I put no because you could compare Seniors and Juniors and Freshman at the same time. But I'm not sure that is right.

Answer (score 1):

Please show your work.
$|A| = 50, |A∪ B| = 80$ so $P(A \cup B) = \frac{|A∪ B|}{140} = \frac{80}{140} = 0.57$. The second should simplify to 1/3, or about 0.33. Probabilities are never more than 1 (or less than 0) so yours can't be right.

The third is right.

Comment: I thought A $\bigcup$ B is 90? 90/140 is .65. For the second I don't know how to do it then. I thought its A and C added together (125/140), divided by C over 140 (75/140).

Comment: How did you get 90? A is 50 and then you add the remainder of $B=Freshman$ which is 30, giving 80.

Comment: Do you not add the male students as well? 10 males + 30 females

Comment: You should only count male freshmen once. Either you count A and the remaining ones in B = (10+15+20+5) + (30) = 50+30, or count B and the remaining ones in A = (30+10) + (15 + 20 + 5) = 40 + 40.

Comment: Ah I understand. I was counting them twice. For the second one you take the intersection of A and C. Divide that by 140. and then take C alone and divide it by 140. Take both results and divide them by each other. So I wound up with (.18/.535) = 0.34. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. It is actually 0.33 but you rounded too much. Also you can do P(A|C) = |A ∩ C| / C which is a bit quicker